# Почему счетчик в цикле for языка Python не добавляет единицу за итерацию?

Tags: python, for, runtime

Я строю скрипт попарного сравнения эмбедингов голосов, чтобы посчитать метрику: как часто ошибается система, когда не может распознать 2 записи одного и того же человека.

В левой части рисунка ниже представлена структура папок: в каждой папке `spk1`, `spk2` и т.д. лежит по 4 файла с голосами одного человека (в каждой директории - разные люди). Сравниваем голоса внутри  папки друг с другом.

[image: Структура папок]

У меня 2 ошибки:

1. то и дело ловлю исключение, которое будто бы свидетельствует об ошибке чтения файла:

> RuntimeError: Error loading audio file: failed to open file spk_12_track_4.wav

Фактически это может говорить, что неверно записан путь к нему.
Однако в моем цикле путь описан шаблонно для прохода по папкам, и
что там некорректного, не понимаю!

2. счетчик num_total при обходе цикла единицу не прибавляет, в результате ловлю исключение деления на ноль. Почему?

Код:

```
!pip install speechbrain
from speechbrain.pretrained import SpeakerRecognition
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import os
from itertools import combinations


num_true=0
num_total=0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/content/drive/MyDrive/speakers'):
    res = list(combinations(files, 2)) # получаем списки кортежей: [(файл 1, файл 2), (файл 1, файл 3)...(файл 3, файл 4)]

    for tuples in res:         # идем по каждому картежу в списке
        verification = SpeakerRecognition.from_hparams(source="speechbrain/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb", savedir="pretrained_models/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb")
        score, prediction = verification.verify_files(f'{tuples[0]}', f'{tuples[1]}')
        num_total+=1
        if prediction == tensor([True]):
            num_true+=1

    if num_total !=0:
      accuracy = num_true/num_total
      print(accuracy)
    else:
      print('На ноль делить нельзя')
```

Comment: print(res) вы зря скрыли

Comment: @Интик, там вот такое:
`[] [('spk_1_track_3.wav', 'spk_1_track_1.wav'), ('spk_1_track_3.wav', 'spk_1_track_2.wav'), ('spk_1_track_3.wav', 'spk_1_track_4.wav'), ('spk_1_track_1.wav', 'spk_1_track_2.wav'), ('spk_1_track_1.wav', 'spk_1_track_4.wav'), ('spk_1_track_2.wav', 'spk_1_track_4.wav')]
[]
[('spk_2_track_1.wav', 'spk_2_track_3.wav'), ('spk_2_track_1.wav', 'spk_2_track_4.wav'), ('spk_2_track_1.wav', 'spk_2_track_2.wav'), ('spk_2_track_3.wav', 'spk_2_track_4.wav'), ('spk_2_track_3.wav', 'spk_2_track_2.wav'), ('spk_2_track_4.wav', 'spk_2_track_2.wav')]
[]` и так далее по файлам и папкам

Comment: Может в каких-то каталогах нет файлов или один файл, тогда внутренний цикл не выполнится ни разу и тотал не прибавится. Судя по распечатке res там действительно есть пустые каталоги.

Comment: А файлы с ошибкой попробуйте открыть программно отдельно. Возможно, они не читаются этой библиотекой

Comment: @CrazyElf, отдельно я открывал - прочитываются